# syntax error /etc/named.conf

Tags: dns, bind

I am trying to configure DNS on RHEL 5 for study purposes.

I have set up forward zones, reverse zones, and `named.conf` files in order to get the DNS working, but when I run `service named start`, I get the following error:[image]

OS: RHEL 5

IPs I am using 172.168.190.1 ... 172.168.190.50

My `/etc/named.conf` file is as follows:

```
options {
        directory "/var/named";
        dump-file "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        listen-on port 53 {any; };
};

zone "oracleexpert.com" IN {
        type master;
        file "oracleexpert.com.fwd.zone";
        allow-update { none; };
};

zone "localhost" IN {
        type master;
        file "localhost.fwd.zone";
        allow-update { none; };
};

zone "190.168.172.in-addr.arpa." IN {
        type master;
        file "172.168.190.rev.zone";
        allow-update { none; };
};

zone "0.0.127.in-addr.arpa." IN {
        type master;
        file "localhost.rev.zone";
    allow-update { none; };
};

zone "0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa." IN {
        type master;
        file "named.ip6.local";
        allow-update { none; };
};

zone "255.in-addr.arpa." IN {
        type master;
        file "named.broadcast";
        allow-update { none; };
};

zone "0.in-addr.arpa." IN {
        type master;
        file "named.zero";
        allow-update { none; };
};

include "/etc/rndc.key";

                                                                                                                50,19         Bot
```

Here is the output of `sed -n l /etc/named.conf`:

```
options {$
\tdirectory "/var/named";$
\tlisten-on port 53 { any; };$
};$
$
zone "oracleexpert.com" IN {$
\ttype master;$
\tfile "oracleexpert.com.fwd.zone";$
\tallow-update { none; };$
};$
$
zone "localhost" IN {$
\ttype master;$
\tfile "localhost.fwd.zone";$
\tallow-update { none; };$
};$
$
zone "190.168.172.in-addr.arpa" IN {$
\ttype master;$
\tfile "172.168.190.rev.zone";$
\tallow-update { none; };$
};$
$
zone "0.0.127.in-addr-arpa" IN {$
\ttype master;$
\tfile "localhost.rev.zone";$
\tallow-update { none; };$
};$
$
zone "255.in-addr.arpa" IN {$
\ttype master;$
\tfile "named.broadcast";$
\tallow-update { none; };$
};$
$
zone "0.in-addr.arpa" IN {$
\ttype master;$
\tfile "named.zero";$
\tallow-update { none; };$
};$
$
include "/etc/rndc.key";$
[root@alpha ~]#
```

Comment: Not to mention that RHEL5 is `EOF (End of Life)` and isn't supported anymore.

Comment: Don't post images of text, please.

Comment: Apologies. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: You are showing two different files in the question. Which file do you have issues with?

Comment: @Kusalananda : the first file /etc/named.conf

Comment: The point is that you have posted ***two different versions*** of `/etc/named.conf`. You should [edit] your question to show *the same version* of the file in both ``cat`` and ``sed -n l`` forms, and the error message that goes with *that* version (because the line numbers have changed). In general, your question should say what you have done to try to solve the problem. Specifically, you should say something like, “I had dots at the ends of names, e.g., `arpa.`, and I took them out (→ `arpa`), and I had a `dump-file` and a `statistics-file`, and I took them out, and yet I get the same error.”

Comment: Well, thank you very much for all your support. I got it rectified. It was a silly mistake I was doing. I had /etc/named.conf and /var/named/chroot/etc/named.conf files and both were slightly different from one another. I just had to match them both in order to get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take out the dots. Instead of:

```
zone "190.168.172.in-addr.arpa." IN {
        type master;
        file "172.168.190.rev.zone";
        allow-update { none; };
};

zone "0.0.127.in-addr.arpa." IN {
        type master;
        file "localhost.rev.zone";
    allow-update { none; };
};
```

It should be:

```
zone "190.168.172.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "172.168.190.rev.zone";
        allow-update { none; };
};

zone "0.0.127.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "localhost.rev.zone";
    allow-update { none; };
};
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I did take out the dots, yet the same error :-(

Comment: @AvinashPawar Can you run `sed -n l /etc/named.conf` and show us how it looks like?

Comment: Sorry, the comments box is reluctant to accept all the characters. The o/p for sed -n l /etc/named.conf is almost 1000 char long

Comment: You can update your question, no need to paste it as comment.

Comment: Don’t say “no need to paste it as comment”; say “***Don’t*** paste it as comment!”  Information that clarifies or refines the question should ***always*** be added to the question, even if it’s only the answer to a “Yes” or “No” question, or some other very short phrase. (Of course it should be comprehensible in context, so don’t say just “Yes”; say (for example) “I have rebooted since the last time I edited the file and the problem persists.”) It is good practice to then post a comment saying that you have updated the question, @-pinging the person who asked for the clarification.